# How do I set up jTweetsAnywhere tweet filter

Tags: jquery, tweets

I am using jTweetsAnywhere (http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/#jta_usage) and need to filter the tweets to exclude certain tweets with words. I have this but it isn't working and there is no examples of how to set this up.

```
 $('#Tweets').jTweetsAnywhere({
            searchParams: ['q=sliderobes'],
            TweetFilter: ['kids'],
            count: 3,
            showTweetFeed: {
                showProfileImages: true,
                showUserScreenNames: false
            }
        })
```

Thanks for any help,
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's lower-case t `tweetFilter` and it's a function that accepts `tweet` - a JSON tweet object straight from the twitter API - and `options`, the plugin options object. For example

```
tweetFilter : function(tweet, options) {
    if (tweet && tweet.text) {
        var text = tweet.text;

        // Reject tweets that mention 'Kids'
        if (text.match(/kids/i)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Passed all filters
        return true;
    }
    // else no object or text - reject
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the comments too! Can you add multiple words to filter?

Comment: Sure, you can put whatever logic you want in the function - e.g. you can repeat that regexp test multiple times if you want.